# CORS Policy Font Error on Wordpress Subdomain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cors

My WordPress website on a subdomain [ collective.terakaia.com ] has recently stopped loading font assets with the following errors in the console. Apologies in advance as I know there are several existing threads regarding the CORS policy issue. I just haven't been able to get any of them to work for my particular situation.

Console Errors:

```
Access to font at 'https://secureservercdn.net/198.71.233.51/e9h.41e.myftpupload.com/wp-content/themes/gridlove/assets/fonts/raleway-semibold-webfont.ttf' from origin 'https://collective.terakaia.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've attempted a few modifications to the .htaccess with no success. Here is the current .htaccess file code:

```
<ifmodule mod_headers.c="">
   SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*\.terakaia\.com)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN}e" env=ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "*"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
</ifmodule>
```

It's very possible that this is just a simple syntax error that I'm just not aware of. I don't have much experience dealing with this kind of issue.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. If Chrome doesn’t show it, use the Network pane in Firefox devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: The response has the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header. So you should be allowed to request the resource. And you should not configure `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on your own server, since this would determine from which sites your content can be loaded. You might want to read up on CORS here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the most recent update of Chrome solves the issue.